# Compare magnification of point and shoot cameras with dSLR telephoto lenses

Tags: lens, dslr, point-and-shoot, magnification

I just want to know how much magnification there is... if I have a point and shoot camera and it has 10X zoom, I'm seeing that the subject is "brought" 10x closer.  So, what does a dSLR telephoto lens need to be to bring the subject 10X closer?  I am looking to buy a 55-200mm Sony lens - will the subject be approximately 10x closer? Or 5x closer or 15x closer?

Comment: Note that that's _not_ what the "10x" means. See the question linked above for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question we need to know two things:

1. The max focal length of the lens (200?)
2. The "normal focal length" for your sensor size (about 45mm on a FF DSLR), but much smaller on a P&S

Now just divide number #1 by #2, so on my FF DSLR a ~200mm lens makes things look 4x closer. The 10x zoom advertising copy on P&S cameras has to do with how large a range the lens covers, which of course has a relationship to how close it can make things look, but by itself cannot answer your question.